# How does one specify (or update) TaxZone when creating/updating Invoice via REST api?

Tags: acumatica

Using acumatica web services (json REST api), how can I set the TaxZone when I create an Invoice. Here's a sample json `put` request:

```
{
    "Date": { "value": "12/23/2019" },
    "DueDate": { "value": "12/23/2019" },
    "Customer": { "value": "12345" },
    "Type": { "value": "Invoice" },
    "LinkBranch": { "value": "MYBRANCH" },
    "FinancialDetails": {
        "TaxZone": { "value": "1" }
    }
}
```

I have tried that, tried `TaxZoneId`, tried posting without using `FinancialDetails` object... nothing seems to work.

Comment: Explain further plz

Comment: This is specific to Acumatica web services API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get the correct structure of the JSON is to send get request with "expand" parameter like below:

http://localhost/ACU19200/entity/Default/18.200.001/SalesInvoice/Invoice|AR007541?$expand=FinancialDetails

This will return you the Invoice record with Financial Details, like below:

```
{
    "id": "7bd77116-dcf1-e911-b312-fc017c8c8936",
    "rowNumber": 1,
    "note": "",
    "Amount": {
        "value": 2385.0000
    },
    "Balance": {
        "value": 1910.0000
    },
    "CashDiscount": {
        "value": 0.0000
    },
    "CreditHold": {
        "value": false
    },
    "Currency": {
        "value": "USD"
    },
    "CustomerID": {
        "value": "ABARTENDE"
    },
    "CustomerOrder": {},
    "Date": {
        "value": "2019-10-18T00:00:00-07:00"
    },
    "Description": {},
    "DueDate": {
        "value": "2019-11-17T00:00:00-08:00"
    },
    "FinancialDetails": {
        "id": "1b004ff5-496f-463e-8b37-f6c74a044482",
        "rowNumber": 1,
        "note": null,
        "BatchNbr": {
            "value": "AR006749"
        },
        "Branch": {
            "value": "PRODWHOLE"
        },
        "CustomerTaxZone": {},
        "custom": {},
        "files": []
    },
    "Hold": {
        "value": false
    },
    "Project": {
        "value": "X"
    },
    "ReferenceNbr": {
        "value": "AR007541"
    },
    "Status": {
        "value": "Open"
    },
    "Type": {
        "value": "Invoice"
    },
    "VATExemptTotal": {
        "value": 0.0000
    },
    "VATTaxableTotal": {
        "value": 0.0000
    },
    "custom": {},
    "files": []
}
```

Now after we have the structure we need to remove the redundant fields from the request and send the PUT request with the JSON like below **(of course in your case you need to also provide invoice details and other information)**:

```
{
    "CreditHold": {
        "value": false
    },
    "Currency": {
        "value": "USD"
    },
    "CustomerID": {
        "value": "ABARTENDE"
    },
    "Description": {
        "value" : "Test Invoice"
    },
    "Hold": {
        "value": false
    },
    "Status": {
        "value": "Open"
    },
    "Type": {
        "value": "Invoice"
    },
    "FinancialDetails": {
        "CustomerTaxZone": {
            "value": "AVALARA"
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to extend the default endpoint if you need to work with AR Invoice (Default/18.200.001/Invoice) because it doesn't contain CustomerTaxZone by default.
You can do it as shown below and then just send CustomerTaxZone as "TaxZone" on the top level.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Samvel! I was able to get it to work on SalesInvoice endpoint. How about Invoice - is FinancialDetails object available there: `...entity/Default/18.200.001/Invoice`